# Are SQL Server 2000+ transactions connection dependent?

Tags: sql-server, connection, transactions

Case 1:

1. I start a connection to the DB
2. I BEGIN a TRANSACTION
3. I close the connection

   What happens to the transaction?

Case 2:

1. I start a connection to the DB
2. I BEGIN a TRANSACTION
3. I start a concurrent connection to the same DB
4. With the second connection I modify the contents of a table
5. With the first connection I ROLLBACK the TRANSACTION

   What happens to the modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: roll back

Case 2: at step 4, you can't modify rows which are touched by the first connection so there's no effect: the second connection can't modify, it will wait (due to the locks).

Comment: What is this "touch" thing? If the first connection modifies row 1 of table A, it means that the other rows are untouched and they can be modified by the second connection during the transaction?

Comment: that depends on the locks taken by sql server.

Comment: @Jader: 'touched' as in: read/modified as connection 1 sets locks on the rows read/modified and connection 2 has to obey those. If the 1st transaction is set to readuncommitted as isolation, connection two may read modified rows, but not alter them

Answer (score 1):

Just to add:
Transactions are session dependent - this explains your first question.